# Sintaxe do angular não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma página *html* que contem o seguinte código:

```
<button 
  class="button button-assertive button-full button-outline centro icon ion-plus"
  option-getter="getOpt(option, complemento)" 
  modal-select="" 
  modal-title="{{complemento.nome}}"
  ng-model="produto.adicionais[complemento.nome]" 
  options="complemento.complementos"
  option-property="nome" 
  multiple="{{ isMultiple(complemento) }}"
  has-search="true">
```

Porém nessa parte eu chamo uma função que retorna `true` ou `false`:

```
multiple="{{ isMultiple(complemento) }}"
```

Ela não está funcionando, a função nem é chamada, o *HTML* final fica com o mesmo código como se fosse uma string.

Já tentei usar sem aspas da seguinte forma:

```
multiple={{ isMultiple(complemento) }}
```

Retornando `"true"` ou `"false"` da função acontecendo a mesma coisa.

Comment: Bom, esse `multiple` deve fazer parte da lib/diretiva que esta usando. Qual o nome/repo dela? Ou foi você quem criou?

Comment: É a ionic-modal-select. (https://github.com/inmagik/ionic-modal-select)

Comment: Tente não usar o `{{ ... }}`. Ex: `multiple="isMultiple(complemento)"`

Comment: Não funciona, já havia testado. Ele reconhece tudo como `true`

Comment: Sim, se vc ver na documentação qualquer valor passado é aceito como true, então tenta retornar null invés de false.

Comment: Mas o problema é justamente esse. A função não é chamada, ela vai como string pro html. Qualquer valor que eu retorne não vai aparecer lá, e os console.log dentro da função tambem não aparecem no console.